# Adding child elements from script task

Tags: ant

I have an `ivy:resolve` task as a part of my ant script. I also have a `script` task that does some processing and generates zero or more module descriptors that need to be excluded from the `ivy:resolve`.

So I need a way for the `script` task to generate some `exclude` elements and add them as children to the `ivy:resolve` task, so that ultimately it ends up with:

```
<ivy:resolve file="${ivy.file.path}">
    <exclude org="generated" module="by a script task" />
    <exclude org="generated" module="by a script task" />
    <exclude org="generated" module="by a script task" />
</ivy:resolve />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't you use ANT properties?

```
  <target name="init">
    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
      project.setProperty("org.to.exclude", "log4j");
      project.setProperty("module.to.exclude", "log4j");
    ]]></script>
  </target>

  <target name="resolve" depends="init">
    <ivy:resolve>
      <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-api" rev="2.7.8"/>
      <exclude org="${org.to.exclude}" module="${module.to.exclude}" />
    </ivy:resolve>
  </target>
```

Comment: That only has one exclude. How do I have a variable number?

Comment: @ICR Sounds like you need to run ivy from within a script then. Could you supply more details of what you're trying to do. Generally creating logical groupings of jars is best done using configurations in ivy. Additionally here is another question where files are being partitioned based on org: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131012/split-organization-name-into-nested-folders-using-ivyretrieve/

Comment: There are some dependencies where usually they come from the repository, but occasionally we need to process and include them into the build differently. I want to be able to specify which these are in a properties file, and then exclude them from the ivy:resolve and process them myself.

Comment: @ICR My point is wouldn't it be a lot simpler (and ivy friendly) to capture these use-cases in the ivy file as two configurations? You wouldn't need a separate properties file there and you'd have a simpler solution. Are you familar with configurations?

Comment: The combination of dependencies that should be excluded varies, and is local, so I'd rather not have people editing the ivy file to change the config because they might accidentally check in the changes.